# Concatenate or add rows to an Astropy Timeseries

Tags: python, time-series, astropy

I'm trying to read multiple CSV files from nightly observations.
Each CSV file has a time and magnitude column and I want to be able to stack all my nightly files into a single Timeseries object.

It is very easy to do with a panda Dataframe (`pd.concat()`) but I cannot find a simple, elegant way with Astropy Timeseries.
I could write the merged file to disk or other solutions but I'm looking for a simple way. It must be doable within astropy Timeseries or Astropy Table I imagine.
Stacking multiple TimeSeries is a common use case.

I tried the following one:

```
from astropy.timeseries import TimeSeries

ts = TimeSeries.read('mydata.csv', format='ascii.csv',time_column='mjd',time_format='mjd')
ts2 = ts.add_row(vals=ts.values()) #imagine that I want to stack with another observation
```

Doing this throw my an Error :
`ValueError: Unable to insert row because of exception in column 'time':`

Any idea while staying in the astropy ecosystem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`astropy.table.vstack`](https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/api/astropy.table.vstack.html#astropy.table.vstack) function (see, e.g., [here](https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/table/operations.html#stack-vertically)). For example, if I had two files `data1.csv` and `data2.csv`, containing:

```
mjd,   mag
54668,  2.4
54669,  2.5
```

and

```
mjd,   mag
54700,  2.6
54701,  2.7
```

respectively, I could do:

```py
from astropy.table import vstack
from astropy.timeseries import TimeSeries

ts = TimeSeries.read("data1.csv", format="ascii.csv", time_column="mjd", time_format="mjd")
ts2 = TimeSeries.read("data2.csv", format="ascii.csv", time_column="mjd", time_format="mjd")

ts = vstack([ts, ts2])
print(ts)
  time  mag
------- ---
54668.0 2.4
54669.0 2.5
54700.0 2.6
54701.0 2.7
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly the kind of solution I was looking for. I had forgotten about vstack. Thanks a lot.